# RegEx for Date conversion

Tags: regex, date

So i have been trying this out for ages but I can't figure it out. I have the following date format :

```
3rd Feb 2016
29th Jan 2016
```

And I want it to convert it to `01/29/2016` and `02/03/2016`.

I have the following code but it doesn't work

```
if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Jan","01",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Feb","02",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Mar","03",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Apr","04",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="May","05",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Jun","06",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Jul","07",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Aug","08",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Sep","09",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Oct","10",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Nov","11",if(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",2)="Dec","12",0)))))))))))) & "/" & if(len(RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",1)) = 1,0&RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",1),RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",1)) & "/" & RegexSplit(Cell(5,6),"([0-9]*)(\w{2}) (\w{3}) (\d{4})",3)
```

Can someone please assist ???

Comment: It is much easier to re-parse the date with a DateTime class. What is the programming language you are using?

Comment: The problem is that we are using some internal program for TabX and apparently we can only use RegX in there...it's a but stupid.